# The property 'PK' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. Error occurs after some successful data entry

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have checked other posts with the related error but in my case it is different since it successfully allows first iteration and occurs in the second iteration of the loop. I am using DataBase first approach in MVC application. In the following code:

```
ACOD a = new ACOD();
int cd = 1;
foreach (var t in e)
{
    a.S1 = t.S1;
    a.S2 = t.S2;
    a.S39 = t.S39;
    a.S40 = t.S40;

    if (db.ACODs.ToList().Count != 0)
    {
         var td = db.ACODs.Max(x => x.N100);
         cd = Convert.ToInt32(td) + 1;
    }
    a.N100 = cd;

    db.ACODs.Add(a);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

N100 is my primary key. I am getting the above mentioned error in the second time the loop iterates. I have disabled the auto entry of N100 so I am generating PK in my code. The loop successfully runs for N100 = 1 but in the second iteration when N100 = 2, the above mentioned error occurs on Add(a) method call.

Where am I wrong? I am using the same methodologies for adding data in similar tables but never got this error.

Comment: Why do you need to modify your PK? Is it not auto-incrementing?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin no, its not auto-increment. I am incrementing it in my code. I am not modifying PK. I just want to add new records.

Comment: Have you tried putting the object creation inside the loop?

Comment: THANKS a lot. it worked for me.. So the problem was the object still pointing towards the previous instance??

Comment: Yes, that's the magic of EF. When you save an instance, EF 'saves' it internally and it's bound to the current Context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you create only one instance of `ACOD` and that you reuse it. For EF, after the first iteration of the loop, you're not adding new entities, you're modifying an existing one.

Try to put the line `ACOD a = new ACOD();` inside the loop, that should fix your problem.