# EF Removing from junction table connecting 3 tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently trying to implement junction table which connects 3 tables. I stucked at removing items from this table.

Connection table's consists of keys of tables and navigations properties to relevant entities. (I simplified this, in full code it has implementation for backing fields)

```
[Table("SeasonHasBroadcast")]
public partial class SeasonHasBroadcastModel : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int SeasonShow {get; set;}

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int SeasonNumber {get; set;}

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [StringLength(45)]
    public string AirtimeDay {get; set;}

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public TimeSpan AirtimeTime {get; set;}     

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 4)]
    [StringLength(45)]
    public string NetworkName {get; set;}

    public virtual AirtimeModel AirtimeLink {get; set;}

    public virtual NetworkModel NetworkLink {get; set;}

    public virtual SeasonModel SeasonLink {get; set;}
}
```

Tables that are connected, among other things, have `public virtual ICollection<SeasonHasBroadcastModel> SeasonHasBroadcasts { get; set; }`.

When I add new entity to this relationship, I just add new entity to this table. Problem is, when I tried remove entities.

What I tried is removing with `SeasonViewModel.Season.SeasonHasBroadcasts.Remove(selected);`. This way I'm removing from others junction tables connecting just 2 tables. Those tables just dont have separate table and exists only via collections. Other try was through navigations properties, where I removed `selected` entity from every collection.

Both of those throws me this error:

> The property 'SeasonShow' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

When I debug and look into DBContext, it shows this error on Shows, Airtimes and networks entities, but not on the junction one.

How to remove from table like this?

Edit

```
public class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

DBContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AirtimeModel>()
    .HasMany(e => e.SeasonHasBroadcasts)
    .WithRequired(e => e.AirtimeLink)
    .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.AirtimeDay, e.AirtimeTime })
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<NetworkModel>()
    .HasMany(e => e.SeasonHasBroadcasts)
    .WithRequired(e => e.NetworkLink)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<SeasonModel>()
    .HasMany(e => e.SeasonHasBroadcasts)
    .WithRequired(e => e.SeasonLink)
    .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.SeasonShow, e.SeasonNumber })
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<SeasonHasBroadcastModel>()
    .Property(e => e.AirtimeDay)
    .IsUnicode(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<SeasonHasBroadcastModel>()
    .Property(e => e.NetworkName)
    .IsUnicode(false);
```

Edit 2 Command for removing broadcast
    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var parrentViewModel = (SeasonViewModel) ParrentViewModel;
        var selected = parrentViewModel.SelectedBroadcast;

```
    if (selected == null) return;

    if (parrentViewModel.Season.SeasonHasBroadcasts.Contains(selected))
    {
        //selected.SeasonLink.SeasonHasBroadcasts.Remove(selected);
        //selected.AirtimeLink.SeasonHasBroadcasts.Remove(selected);
        //selected.NetworkLink.SeasonHasBroadcasts.Remove(selected);

        parrentViewModel.BroadcastsViewModel.Service.DeleteData(selected);

        //parrentViewModel.Service.Context.SeasonHasBroadcasts.Remove(selected);
        //parrentViewModel.Season.SeasonHasBroadcasts.Remove(selected);

    }

    parrentViewModel.SelectedBroadcast = null;
}
```

Command for adding Broadcast:

```
public override void Execute(object parameter)
{
    var parrentViewModel = (SeasonViewModel)ParrentViewModel;

    parrentViewModel.NewBroadcast.SeasonLink = parrentViewModel.Season;

    if (!parrentViewModel.Season.SeasonHasBroadcasts.Contains(parrentViewModel.NewBroadcast))
    {
        parrentViewModel.Season.SeasonHasBroadcasts.Add(parrentViewModel.NewBroadcast);
    }

    parrentViewModel.NewBroadcast = new SeasonHasBroadcastModel();
}
```

Service for: (this is today's attempts, still does not solve, same error)

```
public override void DeleteData(SeasonHasBroadcastModel toDelete)
{
    if (toDelete.AirtimeLink != null && Context.Entry(toDelete.AirtimeLink).State == EntityState.Detached)
        Context.Airtimes.Attach(toDelete.AirtimeLink);

    if (toDelete.NetworkLink != null && Context.Entry(toDelete.NetworkLink).State == EntityState.Detached)
        Context.Networks.Attach(toDelete.NetworkLink);

    if (toDelete.SeasonLink != null && Context.Entry(toDelete.SeasonLink).State == EntityState.Detached)
        Context.Seasons.Attach(toDelete.SeasonLink);

    base.DeleteData(toDelete);
}
```

Base.DeleteData:

```
public virtual void DeleteData(TModel toDelete)
{
    _context.Set<TModel>().Remove(toDelete);
}
```

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you using? Also what is the type of the exception thrown? Further you mention a lot of other objects of your system for which there is no code shown. I feel it is hard to gain a full picture of what is going on in your code.

Comment: It throws InvalistOperationException, message is in OP. EF is version 6.1.3

Comment: Have you set up any FluentApi configuration on your DbContext class? Would be nice to see that. Also the relevant parts of your tables connected to your join table `SeasonHasBroadcastModel ` as well as your `BaseModel`.

Comment: Is it valid these days to mark types such as `String` and `TimeSpan` as part of the Primary Key of a Table?

Comment: DbContext was created by VS (database first). Code added to OP. 

About the parts, I think everything important should be there (I dont want to send here tons of unrelevant code). I created tables via SQL and classes were created by VS. Base model will be in OP too.

About PK I'm not sure, I was modelling this only by SQL, for EF I decided when implementing application.

Comment: I see that you added more code. Good. In the meantime try this google search: `The property is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. +"database first"`. One result I found was this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049216/the-property-pk-is-part-of-the-objects-key-information-and-cannot-be-modified

Comment: Sorry for spamming the comment section but since you seem to be in charge of the database I would strongly recommend taking the `Code First` approach because `Database First` is something suggested for cases where you start with an existing database you can't really change and therefore have to have code generated for it by EF which doesn't always turn out or work they way you want it to. That is from my own experience as well. **Edit**: You could for example take the generated Code pretend its `Code First` and see if EF creates the same database you started out with. I wager it won't.

Comment: I already tried googling (even here on stack). I had this problem with two tables connected, but solved it. And lots of those problem are when adding, i have problem when removing. The error occurs at the remove line. Thisproblem shouldnt be it- i did not create new instance for removing, just assign entity or null.

Comment: You can't modify part of the key, okay.  Can you remove the current version then add the updated version?  Natural keys are a PITA sometimes, and are usually better avoided unless you have a good think about possible side effects like this.

Comment: @Will I know that, I dont want to modify, I want to remove entity, but I cant. This table is just add/remove entities, nothing with modife.

Comment: Aaah, derp.  Good luck.

Comment: It might be related to cascade delete being turn off. Did you try `Remove` directly from `DbSet<SeasonHasBroadcastModel>` (instead from navigation property)?

Comment: `parrentViewModel.Service.Context.SeasonHasBroadcasts.Remove(selected);` I tried even this, same result. Or you mena something else?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Well, it's hard to help w/o repro - can you provide sample code (a.k.a. [mcve]).

Comment: I added some more code. I dont want to post here whole classes o code, because some of classes are a little bit long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after consulting it with professor at my college, we reached to "easiest" solution will probably be stored procedure on SQL server. Its not the best sollution, but its working. Still wonder, how to do this without stored procedure.